# PyCharm loops one less than expected and adds empty spaces to list inexplicably

Tags: python, list, pycharm

In this code I want to enter elements in the list and display the list as ouput. but I am getting different output than desired. When I entered 4 elements, it allows me to enter only three and gives output only 2 elements while there is 2 empty elements. Can you help? I am using Pycharm.

```
g = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
fruit_list = []
print("Enter the elements: ")
i = 0
while i < g:
    fruit_list.append(input())
    i += 1

print(fruit_list)
```

***OUTPUT***

```
Enter the number of elements: 4
Enter the elements: 
John
Bill
Sam
['John', '', 'Bill', '']
```

Comment: Where and how exactly are you executing this code?

Comment: Looks like the `return` used to indicate the end of a name is also being treated as a blank input; *why* that is happening would depend (at least in part) on the answer to @deceze's question.

Comment: Also, a `for` loop will be more suitable to take fixed number of inputs as long as you don't do any validation.

Comment: This is very strange. The loop should run 4 times and yet only 3 inputs are shown magically producing 4 outputs (elements in the list)

Comment: @ScottHunter  when I tried running this with Debug it runs fine and gives the desired result. I am using pycharm.

Comment: @buran I have tried `for` loop also but the result is exactly same.

Comment: I have just tried this in PyCharm CE and get the same nonsense results - investigating. Top tip - Don't use PyCharm

Comment: @deceze I am running this in pycharm

Comment: Does the same happen if you use `for _ in range(g)` instead of `while i < g`

Comment: can you suggest a better IDE for python? @AlbertWinestein

Comment: *How* exactly? Simply typing into a file and running it? Or the interactive Python interpreter? Put this information into your question.

Comment: yes got the same annoying result @Sayse

Comment: This is a PyCharm issue. I will add the relevant tag to the question

Comment: is there any way to solve this problem? @AlbertWinestein

Comment: Can you reduce your mcve at all? I'd suggest it might be reproducable (with pycharm which i dont use) with either just `print([input()])` or just the `fruit_list.append(input())` and printing that rather than having to loop

Comment: @baduker [tag:pycharm] appears to be the crucial piece of information here! Don't remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be resolved in PyCharm by editing the Run/Debug settings. Under 'Execution', select 'Run with Python Console'.

This would not be an issue if executed outside of PyCharm - i.e., direct invocation of python